# How to Generate Android Testing Report in HTML Automatically

Tags: android, unit-testing

I would like to automatically generate unit testing report in html format for Android application on Hudson continuous integration server.

Therefore, I try to run test cases first and gather test result files in xml format. Then, I use JUnitReport Task to transform the XML result files into HTML format.

I run test cases through Android instrumentation framework. However, it only provides verbose output information rather than the standard JUnit XML format. I have no idea how to generate HTML unit test report without JUnit XML result files.

If I run test cases using Eclipse, it can export results in XML files with time consumed information per test case. Those XML files can be transformed into HTML by JUnitReport Task correctly. As a result, it seems that it is possible to collect the test result with time consumed information.

Is there any way to get the standard JUnit XML result file automatically after running test cases on Android instrumentation framework?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We had similar problem in our company. We checked all the available open-source solutions and none of them was really perfect. So we developed and just open-sourced a solution for it. I still do not say an "ultimate" one but certainly much better than either athena or the python reporter or any after-test analysis. You can find it here:
http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/

It provides:

- separate XML file per each package involved
- XML files are generated on the device (need to be adb pull'ed after test)
- timing of the tests is fully supported
- we have full stack trace reported in failure/error case

Instead of analysing java source code (as in athena) or analysing the output (the python script), we extended android instrumentation runner. So we get all the benefits of using standard command line options for test selection, coverage enabling etc. - all described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsCommand.

We were able to successfully run the code using standard test rules with coverage analysed by emma, all nicely reported in Jenkins.

Comment: Just tried your solution it works nearly strait forward with Jenkins. Thanks!

Comment: Just found a similar solution as yours: https://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible, so you need to create a utility that converts the Android test runner output into JUnit-format XML files.

However, you won't be able to get the time-per-test value, as the Android test runner doesn't seem to output that information.

Comment: Interesting; I've seen the Android test runner output and looked at the source code previously but didn't see anything about outputting times. So I wonder how it works in Eclipse. I guess a look at the ADT plugin is in order...

Comment: I looked into the runner's source and found nothing, too. But I found that there are two test runner output parsers written in Java and Python in path "/development/testrunner" and "/development/tools/ddms" respectively. They help a lot to parse the test runner's verbose output. Surprisingly, both of them use "performance" as key to fetch time information. Furthermore, test cases for output parser in path "/development/testrunner/tests" contain performance test data. So I think there should be a way to turn on performance output.

Comment: Ah ok, though I'm not quite sure what "performance" refers to. Is that not something where you have to instrument your code? Anyway, I looked at the Android Eclipse plugin the other day, that *does* have code where it calculates the time for each test run, as it's required by the Eclipse JUnit infrastructure. The Eclipse plugin test runner sends 'test started' and 'test ended' events, so it's trivial to calculate the execution time as it happens.

Comment: Add annotation @android.test.TimedTest for test cases will make test runner output time information.

Comment: That API isn't yet public. Why can't they just output that information in the first place anyway? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the **athena** approach is the lest painfull as you can simply install the athena jar file on your system and add following ant target

```
<property name="junit.dir" value="${basedir}/junit-results"/>
<property name="athena.jar" value="/home/cruise/athena/athena-1.1.2.jar"/>

<target name="prepare" description="Setup needed directories">
  <mkdir dir="${junit.dir}"/>
</target>

<!-- This target will compile/install tested project as well as test project to ensure tests are executed against latest code -->
<target name="athena" depends="prepare, -install-tested-project, install" description="Run tests and convert result to xml using athena">
  <exec executable="java" os="Linux" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-cp"/>
    <arg value="${athena.jar}"/>
    <arg value="com.synaptik.athena.Athena"/>
    <arg value="${basedir}"/>
    <arg value="${junit.dir}/TEST-result.xml"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

From command line it is then simply a matter of running **ant athena** and you have the test result in xml. This will also be the target your CruiseControl script should trigger.