# How to retrieve test results when using "adb shell am instrument"

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm executing some tests in my Android device by using the following command:

> adb shell am instrument -w
>   package.name/android.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

I can see the test progress and simple results through STDOUT. But, does this process also generates a results file inside the device (xml, html, etc)? If yes, where is it stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But, does this process also generates a results file inside the device (xml, html, etc)?

No, it does not.

Report generation is generally handled at a higher layer than 'am instrument'. If you run your tests using Gradle, it should generate the report for you. I believe this is what Android Studio relies on as well.

If you must generate the report from the test itself, you can use a custom test runner. See this answer for one way to do it: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/5574418/1999084

Comment: Is there any solution/approach to have the test results displayed in a better way then? I'm asking this because when I run the tests through Android Studio it generates the junit tests output in xml, html, etc.

Comment: Report generation is generally handled at a higher layer than 'am instrument'. If you run your tests using Gradle, it should generate the report for you. I believe this is what Android Studio relies on as well.

Comment: If you must generate the report from the test itself, you can use a custom test runner. See this answer for one way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5574418/1999084

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Could you add those information in your main answer?

Comment: Just an additional information: If you are using the test runner that google page is recommending (AndroidJUnitRunner), probably the solution pointed out in this reply will not work. I found the solution in this great article: http://www.everybodytests.com/2015/04/jenkins-devices-androidjunitrunner.html

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem (I wanted to have xml test reports for my Jenkins when it runs instrumentation tests on a device). I solved it by implementing the "android-xml-run-listener" (https://github.com/schroepf/TestLab/tree/master/android).

To use it simply add:

```
androidTestCompile 'de.schroepf:android-xml-run-listener:0.1.3'
```

to your build.gradle (note the androidTest prefix - this will not add code to your production app!).

To use it, add:

```
-e listener de.schroepf.androidxmlrunlistener.XmlRunListener
```

to your am instrument command.

And to retrieve the XML report file, use:

```
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<your-app-package-name>/files/report.xml
```

Comment: I am not able to see the report.xml generated on android emulator 5.1.1 device..Can you please help?

Comment: hi @rupeshjain looks like on older android versions the `emulated/0` directory doesn't exist... For me I had to use `/storage/sdcard/Android/data/de.schroepf.demoapp/files` to access the reports on a 5.x emulator...

Answer (score 3):

If you are executing your tests using `AndroidTestOrchestrator` your XML test results are generated and stored inside the devices `storage/emulated/0/odo/` directory. So they can be accessed using:

`adb pull storage/emulated/0/odo/`

I'm not sure why this isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation. 
This path is likely to be different for real devices, where I believe the results are outputted on the SDCARD somewhere.

Comment: This still seems to work. I thought it had stopped working in recent emulators, but it turns out I wasn't running the tests with Test Orchestrator.

Comment: is this still works?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar situation and found https://docs.marathonlabs.io/ works great for my use case. Other options I've looked into:

- https://docs.marathonlabs.io/ is an effort similar to spoon but seems to be more updated and better maintained. It also provides nice HTML reports with additional features like tests batching, retrying and screen recording.
- https://github.com/square/spoon is a test runner wrapper on top of adb shell am instrument which first runs with -e log true to get a list of available Espresso tests, and then run each test case one-by-one with -r flag so that we can be getting the XML test result from the raw text output as well runtime at the per testcase level. I didn't go down this route because it makes our overall test execution time a lot longer.
- Use https://github.com/jamesknowsbest/Instrumentationpretty to parse the output from instrumentation tests raw log (-r) flag. We will be able to generate an XML JUnit test result with all info, except for test execution time at the test case level.
- Use `adb shell am instrument -f <proto_file>` to store the instrumentation result in a protobuf file, read it in and convert it to junit xml file. Looking at the [Android instrument source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/am/src/com/android/commands/am/Instrument.java#226) for `am/instrument.java`, it seems the testlevel runtime are kept when we run it with -f instead of -r. But this means we will have to create our own protobuf parser file to generate the Junit-style XML file yourself.
- https://github.com/schroepf/TestLab/tree/master/android is another Open source tool created to add instrumentation data inside the application (as opposed to the client / runner side approach above). It should create a JUnit style XML result inside the Android emulator and we can then use adb pull to pull it out of the emulator afterwards.