# Jacoco Coverage Report issues

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, test-coverage

I am trying to define the location, where jacoco will create the coverage file for instrumentation tests running on real devices.

From the `--debug` run of the gradle task I see this log:

```
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] DeviceConnector 'Nexus 5X - 6.0.1': installing /home/martin/workspace/lib/my-lib/build/outputs/apk/my-lib-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
[INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Starting 1 tests on Nexus 5X - 6.0.1
[INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task]  de.my.lib.utils.UtilsTest testMyTest[Nexus 5X - 6.0.1] [32mSUCCESS [0m
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] DeviceConnector 'Nexus 5X - 6.0.1': fetching coverage data from /data/data/de.my.lib.test/coverage.ec
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] DeviceConnector 'Nexus 5X - 6.0.1': uninstalling de.my.lib.test 13:46:14.538
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':my-lib:connectedDebugAndroidTest'
```

I tried 3 ways to define the location:

Using the `<instrumentation>` tag in the manifest file didn't change anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="de.my.lib.test"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:targetPackage="de.my.lib.test"
        tools:replace="android:targetPackage">
        <meta-data
            android:name="coverage"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="coverageFile"
            android:value="/sdcard/coverage.ec" />
    </instrumentation>
</manifest>
```

I tried it with gradle but the output was the same:

```
defaultConfig {
    // unimportant stuff
    testApplicationId "de.my.lib.test"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testInstrumentationRunnerArgument('coverageFile', '/sdcard/coverage.ec')
}
```

And finally I tried it with `adb` command:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e coverage true -e coverageFile /sdcard/coverage.ec de.my.lib.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

But there I get 2 errors:

> de.my.lib.utils.UtilsTest:.
>   Could not find class: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.CoverageTransformer
>       .
>   Time: 0,072
>
> OK (1 test)
>
> Error: Failed to generate emma coverage.

I am completely lost here. Any ideas?

**Background** Why I need it to have it stored in another place: There is a bug with `adb shell run-as` command on some devices and Android version so I have devices in my test device farm which return 0% coverage because the file can't be pulled. So I need the file to be stored in a publicly available location.

Answer (score 3):

> However, the coverage report is not generated yet. To enable this option, we need to add a property to our debug build variant. Using the Android plugin DSL, we can enable the coverage through the `testCoverageEnabled` property:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

> To enable the coverage report for local tests when using version **2.2.+** of Android Gradle plugin, you need to enable it in your app’s `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    //...

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The **instrumentation** performed by Jacoco produces execution files that contain the necessary data to create the report (HTML, XML, etc.). The problem here, is that Espresso generates `.ec` file, while the unit tests execution generates `.exec` file… we have different formats!
>
> As we are not able to configure the coverage task of Espresso, we must ensure that it is executed first. Next, we need to run unit tests, and then create the coverage data with both files (`ec` and `exec`).
>
> To enable this, we need to edit our task once more and add the `coverage.ec` file as a parameter in `executionData` property:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec", 
            "outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec"
    ])
}
```

> As Android Gradle plugin 2.2.+ now generates a coverage file for each execution, using the device / emulator in the file name, now we need to pass every file to execution data, as the file name is now dynamic. In addition, I added the `createDebugCoverageReport` task as a dependency of our custom task, so we don’t need to run it manually :)
>
> Finally, when we execute both tasks, running the Espresso tests first, we will get the unified coverage report!

```
gradle clean jacocoTestReport
```

For detailed explanation see [here](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa).

## Edit:

So, the command `adb shell am instrument` does not generates the report, for this you have to handle it using gradle solution. If you really want to test it your self, then you've to use a [custom runner](https://code.google.com/archive/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/).

References:

1) [How to Generate Android Testing Report in HTML Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178870/how-to-generate-android-testing-report-in-html-automatically)

2) [How to retrieve test results when using "adb shell am instrument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896315/how-to-retrieve-test-results-when-using-adb-shell-am-instrument)

3) https://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report

---

[Test from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line)

---

Updated to Command line method follow [these](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/11/obtaining-code-coverage-of-running.html) steps.

**Running the instrumented application**

Once we have the `EmmaInstrumentation` class (is in ref link) in place we need a few more adjustments to be able to get the coverage report of the running application.

Firstly, we need to add the new Activity to the manifest. Secondly, we should allow our application to write to the sdcard if this is where we decided to generate the coverage report. To do it you should grant the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
Then, it's time to build and install the instrumented apk:

```
$ ant clean
$ ant instrument
$ ant installi
```

Everything is ready to start the instrumented application

```
$ adb shell am instrument -e coverage true \
    -w com.example.i2at.tc/\
        com.example.instrumentation.EmmaInstrumentation
```

[Here](https://github.com/dtmilano/TemperatureConverter) is Source code.

Comment: No not the gradle way but from `"adb shell am instrument..."`

Comment: Idea is to get it via command line since we are testing system applications. it uses mk file to generate build unlike general way i.e. using gradle script.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I've updated my answer please see that if helps you.

Comment: Thanks for putting too much effort. But we are not using ant. Also whatever you mentioned we have already tried.

Comment: I figured the root cause. Posted an answer. Check once.

Answer (score 1):

For us it was an AOSP app. We were generating the test and module apks with disabling Jack compiler which was causing this further issue. Because for us Jack compiler was needed to generate `coverage.em`. But the error was not quite relevant. So had no clue to go any further.

**So the fix was to run the jack compiler server and get the apks generated using it.**

Comment: how is this answer related to the error message in the question? there is no single word about `coverage.em` not being found, but `CoverageTransformer` not being found.

Comment: Read the answer again. @MartinZeitler The error was same as in question.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I check that your answer is about after release of application while in the question there is not mentioned that thing; its only say about the debugging the application so my answer was based on that thing. BTW I'm feeling happy; you fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

the missing [CoverageTransformer](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/org.jacoco.agent.rt/src/org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal/CoverageTransformer.java) class hints for a missing dependency to the JaCoCo agent runtime. one simple solution approach might be, to provide it with what it demands (to be available on device):

```
testImplementation "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.3"
```

in case you get a `FileNotFoundException`, when the `ClassNotFoundException` was fixed, make sure to have the permission to write to SD card, which appears to be another possible pitfall:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

as I've just seen, there is also an [org.jacoco.report](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.8.3) package, which could be optionally added:

```
testImplementation "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.8.3"
```

package `org.jacoco.agent` is in every case the one which contains class `CoverageTransformer`.