# UIAutomator Test Report

Tags: android-uiautomator

I could not be able to find any information about how to genarate uiautomator test reports in xml format. I have found out that log-converter may be used for this purpose but I wonder if the tool (uiautomator) has report generation property itself?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI Automator does not provide this functionality. Report generation is usually handled at a layer outside of the test itself (by the test runner or test harness). For example, if you run your tests using Gradle, it will handle the report generation for you.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901239/1999084 for some more discussion on a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using uiautomator 1.0, the console output is Junit format, you can use Junit test report converter.

If you are using uiautomator 2.0, just run the command

```
gradlew cC
```

the report will generate by android gradle plugin automatically and locate at `${YOUR_MODULE}\build\report`.